# Makefile wildcard issue

Tags: makefile, wildcard

I am trying to write a makefile to selectively include a certain file.

I have manage to get it working with the following:

```
OBJS := $(filter-out ./build/./src/class_1.cpp.o, $(OBJS))
OBJS := $(filter-out ./build/./src/class_2.cpp.o, $(OBJS))

OBJS_1 :=./build/./src/class_1.cpp.o $(OBJS)
OBJS_2 := ./build/./src/class_2.cpp.o $(OBJS)
```

But I would like to make it more generic and use a wildcard.

My understanding is that the following should work:

```
OBJS := $(filter-out $(wildcard ./build/./src/*), $(OBJS))
```

I also tried

```
OBJS := $(filter-out $(wildcard \./build/\./src/*), $(OBJS))
```

but not sure if the problem is with the special symbols or just a basic understanding.

however it then complains about having too many main functions (class 1 and class 2).

Is there something that I am missing with my understanding of wildcard and filters in make?

If I print out the value of $(OBJS) with the two different approaches, the values are identical, so I am not sure why one solution could work while the other one fails.

However, for some reason `OBJS_1` doesn't seem to get the filter that was applied to `$(OBJS)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(wildcard ...)` function finds which files actually exist in the filesystem (and some or all .o files might be created during make's execution, thus the result will be different depending on the last command). This is most certainly not what you want.

In your case you need only to perform the string substitution, and the 'match-all' pattern for strings in make is a percent-sign. So it should be:

```
OBJS:=$(filter-out ./build/./src/%,$(OBJS))
```

Also note that spaces in the makefile may have significance. For example, `$(filter a, b)` means that the second argument is " b", not just "b". Even though it wouldn't matter in your case, you should be more cautious with spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have been more specific about what I am trying to do. I want to filter out the files only in that directory (and not in the subdirectories). This didn't seem to work correctly. But it definitely is putting me down the right track.

Comment: I managed to get it working by putting the files I wanted control over in their own directly, but not sure how I would have solved this without doing that.